# VB.Net Get scope_identity() to be used in a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using a VB.Net transaction to execute two queries. There are two tables & following is an example structure.

```
USER
----
1. USER_ID - int (PK) AUTO_INCREMENT
2. USER_NAME - varchar(20)

ADDRESS
-----
1. USER_ID
2. USER_ADDRESS
```

As this basic structure represents a USER can have many photos. Whenever I insert a new record to the USER table photos of the user should be saved with the USER_ID which was automatically created.

I know that I need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() for this purpose but I always get NULL for the SCOPE_IDENTITY() value, this isn't because of a trigger or anything else. Issue lies on how VB.Net creates my INSERT statement.

Here is how the queries look like in the SQLServer Profiler

**Insert to the USER Table**

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO USER(USER_NAME) VALUES (@USER_NAME)',N'@USER_NAME nvarchar(4)',@USER_NAME =N'ABCD'
```

**Insert to the ADDRESS Table**

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO ADDRESS(USER_ID,USER_ADDRESS) VALUES ((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()),@USER_ADDRESS)',N'@ USER_ADDRESS nvarchar(10)',@USER_ADDRESS=N'ABCDEFGHIJ'
```

I have appended the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() directly in to the second query & I think SQL thinks that the command SCOPE_IDENTITY() is a string, how do I prevent this from happening.

Comment: You **may** need to remove the brackets `()`.

Comment: Show the vb code used to send those queries to the db.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå if I don't use the brackets it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. so I guess the brackets should be there..

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The VB code prepares queries dynamically, it is hard to post that code in a way that would be easier for others to understand because I have separated the functions to separate modules for my own flexibility. The above sql's are from the profile which means that the vb code doesn't have any issues right ?

Comment: You can create a output parameter in your first query and assign `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to it and then use it in your second query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name implies, `scope_identity()` is local to a scope.  And `sp_executesql` runs inside [its own scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).  A later call to `sp_executesql` has no memories of the earlier scope.

The most logical solution would be to run both queries in the same scope.  I'm not sure why you are using `sp_executesql`; perhaps you can omit that.  Most clients run something like:

```
INSERT INTO USER(USER_NAME) VALUES (@USER_NAME);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID;
```

The client program can get the `ID` from the resulting row set.  It can then pass the `ID` as a parameter to the `INSERT` queries for addresses.  No `sp_executesql` required.

If you must use more than one `sp_executesql`, consider using an`output` parameter to ferry the identity out:

```
declare @ID bigint

exec sp_executesql 
    N'INSERT INTO USER(USER_NAME) VALUES (@USER_NAME);
      SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();',
    N'@USER_NAME nvarchar(4), @ID bigint output',
    @USER_NAME = N'ABCD',
    @ID = @ID output;
```

You can now pass `@ID` as a variable to your second `sp_executesql`.

Comment: .Net parameterized queries use sp_executesql behind the scenes. Since he's using a profiler, this is what normal queries would look like.